# Как проверить количество символов введенных в Edit?

Tags: delphi, строки, vcl

Как сделать, чтобы если в `Edit1` введено меньше двух символов (букв, цифр), то кнопка была бы не активна.

Я делаю это так и это условие прописываю в самом edit1:

```
if Edit1.text < '2' then
  Button1.Enabled := False
else
  Button1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Но почемуто не срабатывает. Ввожу любой символ меньше двух, но кнопка по прежнему активна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Татьяна, правильно сделать так:

```
if Length(Edit1.Text) < 2 then
  Здесь дальнейший Ваш код.
```

В Вашем первоначальном коде вы делаете сравнение **не длины введенного текста**, но **значение введенного текста**.

Для того, чтобы получить значение длины введенного текста в компоненте `Edit1` (это также относится к строковым типам данных и массивам), следует использовать функцию `Length`. Ее деятельность заключается в возврате числа элементов в массиве или строке. Массив или строка указываются как аргумент данной функции.